# Generic cast error - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Int32'?

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting

We have a `CustomerDict` which is `IDictionary<string, object>` from which we are trying to get key value but we are casting it as an `object`:

```
int clientId = someDefaultValue;
//...
holder.CustomerDict.TryGetValue("clientId", out object procId)
clientId = (int) procId;
```

But this line `clientId = (int) procId;` throws cast exception that it cannot cast `double` into `integer` and value of `clientId` is Integer only which I have already confirmed so why it is considering as `double` then?

This is the error I get:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Int32'.
```

So I was trying to reproduce this with below code but couldn't and it works fine.

```
IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("cat", 2);
dictionary.Add("dog", 1);

int cat = 10;
dictionary.TryGetValue("cat", out object catId);
cat = (int)catId;
Console.WriteLine(cat);
```

I am confuse why my original code throws exception but my test code works fine? Also what should be the right way to fix my original code?

Comment: Well how is your `CustomerDict` being populated? Presumably it really *does* have a `double` value in, even if it's a whole number. But without knowing what's populating it, we can't guess what's going on.

Comment: My guess is you are adding items to the CustomerDict based on the result of some kind of math that is returning a double. Just a guess tho, until you answer @JonSkeet above.

Comment: Problem is that you try to cast not double to integer (which has implicit convertor), but objeft to integer. Try this way: `clientId = (int)(double)procId` and it will work. However, it's better for safety use `Convert.ToInt32()` as @jcHernande2 answered

Comment: @JonSkeet It's a JSON that is getting deserialized into this dictionary looks like.

Comment: The fact that you have to use an object says it all. Nail down your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ToInt32(value)` to convert `double` to `int`:

```
dictionary.TryGetValue("cat", out object catId);
int cat = Convert.ToInt32(catId);
```

other option

```
if (Int32.TryParse(catId.ToString(), out int cat)) {
  // it is a number
} else {
  // it is not a number
}
```

Comment: I think it would probably be better to fix whatever's producing the dictionary, if it's really intended to be an `int`.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's a JSON that is getting deserialized into this dictionary looks like and json has integer value in them for `clientId`.

Comment: @AndyP: Well presumably it's the JSON serializer deciding to treat all numbers as `double` values, which isn't entirely unreasonable. This is why it's really useful to provide a [mcve] in questions. We don't know how you're deserializing, or what JSON library you're using - there may be an option to use `int` where possible, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon. Got it now. I will make sure that next time. Sorry about that. We use `Utf8Json` library to deserialize JSON into POCO just fyi if that helps to figure out why it is doing that.